# Pandas version upgrade for Airflow in docker compose

Tags: pandas, airflow

I have installed Airflow in docker compose from official documentation. Everything is ok, but Airflow uses pandas 2.0.3 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiR6t.png), but i need pandas 2.2.0.
Before updating the pandas i need to update python[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0ILo.png).
Current Python version is 3.8.18 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evPUv.png).

I've installed Python3.11 with command sudo apt install python3.11, but default Python version is 3.8.18. I also tried to update alternatives with command sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.8 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSPtk.png)

Please help. My main goal is to update Pandas.
Thanks
BR Andrey

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Post them as text instead.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)